# Muslim vassals after winning war for province?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

So after fabricating a claim on Tunis, I attacked and won as King of Sicily. I also made sure to wait until every holding was successfully besieged.

But now, I only hold the barony. All other holdings are still held by the muslims that originally held them. How can this be? Shouldn't they be removed? Why are they still there, and how would I prevent this from happening in the future?

I know that I can revoke their titles with medium crown authority. But how do I prevent this situation in the first place?

Comment: Which game are you talking about?

Comment: CK2. I'm sorry for including the CK flag, I didnt know it would make that unclear.

Comment: @Honeyboy We use tags to categorize questions according to the game they're about in a consistent and easy to understand way (for example, I originally thought your question was about Europa Universalis IV). This allows users to quickly verify that A) they like the game enough to be willing to answer and B) they know enough about the game that they can give a reasonable answer. We also have several site features that use tags to grant knowledgeable people trophies or even allow people to ignore questions about games they don't like.

Comment: Wait, how did you think this was about EUIV, when it is tagged as "crusader-kings-2"? I dont understand

Answer (score 1):

Unless you had a claim on the duchy or kingdom level of Tunis then your claim war was only for the province.

Before declaring war you can see the "Win, Draw and Lose" conditions in the GUI and the consequences of those results.

If you looked at this just before declaring war, you would have seen that the result of winning was "your ruler name" becomes "title" of Tunis (the province, not the duchy/kingdom/empire).

Comment: Also note (if I'm remembering correctly, its been a while since I last played) that if you claimed the duchy or kingdom, you'd normally only get the duchy/kingdom title and the counties in the duchy/kingdom owned by the previous ruler. The other counties would remain held their previous owners, except those that had the defeated ruler as their liege would now become your vassals. Certain *casus belli* like crusades gain you all the titles in the duchy/kingdom, or at least all those not owned by rulers of the same religion, but normal wars just gain you the title you're claiming.

Answer (score 1):

The Aristocrats/clergy who do not belong to your religion will be removed if and only if your casus belli was Holy War. That will remove all heathens from your nice conquered territories, allowing you to plant aristocrats/clergy who are followers of the same religion as you.

As you stated, your casus belli was "Conquest as a Claimant", as a result you only got the duchy.

When the game starts, it warns you that "Choose your Casus Belli Wisely".

This is how claim wars work:

The [possible outcomes](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Casus_Belli#Claim_wars) are:

> 1. Upon winning a claim war you will gain the title and you'll gain 100 prestige.
> 2. If it ends in a stalemate you'll lose 100 prestige
> 3. If it ends in loss, the claim will be lost in addition to 200 prestige.

As to how did you get a barony somehow, I suspect you had a claim on the barony as well and pressed all your claims against the defender. You couldn't have had fabricated it since Chancellors can only fabricate claims on counties (Thereby giving you a claim on capital barony of the county technically). So one of these might be true:

1. You had a claim on county as well and chose "Press all claims" against the defender. Result was you gaining both the duchy and the county (The capital barony technically although it will show up as a county).
2. You fabricated claim on the duchy but had inherited a claim on the barony by blood. That is only possible if you are descended from a Muslim claimant of that barony or some other holder of that barony who may have lost his/her title to Muslims, making him/her landless and giving them a strong inheritable claim. Then you pressed all claims and got both duchy and barony.